# Angular Binding/Scope problems

Tags: angularjs

Maybe this is an angular bug, but I feel like I've got a fundamental misunderstanding of how something is working here and my google-fu is failing me.

I have a pretty simple DOM, which is loaded as a partial view dynamically.  The rest of the page doesn't use angular.  There is an ng-app on a div further up the DOM.

```
<div class="partialContainer bootstrap" id="dataEntryTab" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-model="$scope">
        <p>Target types: {{targetTypes}}</p>
        <ul ng-repeat="tt in targetTypes">
            <li>
                <h2>{{tt.DisplayName}} Targets</h2>
                <ul class="targetList" ng-repeat="t in targetsOfType(tt.Name)">
                    <li>
                        <span>{{t.Name}}</span><span>{{t.EnteredData.length}} trials</span>
                        <span ng-repeat="d in enteredData">
                            <span>{{d}}</span>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addData()">Enter Data</button>
</div>
```

When the partial view loads, this function fires, which as far as I understand it, gets angular rolling:

```
$('#dataEntryTab').live('tabLoad', () => {
    var invoker = $compile => {
        var scope = angular.element('#dataEntryTab').scope();
        $compile('#dataEntryTab')(scope);
    }
    invoker.$inject = ['$compile'];
    angular.element('#content-wrapper-1').injector().invoke(invoker);
});
```

The issue I'm running into is, without the ng-model on this line:
        `<div ng-model="$scope">`
the ng-repeat below it renders as empty.  I assume the problem is either it's bound incorrectly, or the scope is wrong.  But I am far too new to angular to figure out which or how to fix it.

One thing that I know that I don't know is how angular matches up scope between the DOM and the controller.

For reference, this is the controller code (in typescript):

```
var mainController = ($scope: IMainScope, targetTypeFilter: ITargetTypeFilterFunc, ngDialog: IDialog, dataEntry: IDataEntryService) => {
    $scope.targetsOfType = (targetType: string) => {
        return targetTypeFilter(dataEntry.enteredData, targetType);
    };

    $scope.addData = () => {
        ngDialog.open({
            template: 'addDataDialog',
            scope: $scope
        });
    };
    $scope.targetTypes = [
        new TargetType('DTT', 1, 'DTT'),
        new TargetType('TaskAnalysis', 3, 'Task Analysis'),
        new TargetType('Duration', 4, 'Duration'),
        new TargetType('Frequency', 5, 'Frequency'),
        new TargetType('Toileting', 6, 'Toileting'),
        new TargetType('Fluency', 7, 'Fluency'),
        new TargetType('Quantity', 8, 'Quantity'),
        new TargetType('Anecdotal', 9, 'Anecdotal'),
        new TargetType('GroupedFrequency', 14, 'Grouped Frequency'),
    ];

};
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live()` has been deprecated for years. Where is that jQuery code?

Comment: We're using jQuery 1.11.1.  That live() snippet is at the very end of the js/ts file containing my angular code.

Comment: and it's not throwing error? Was completely removed in 1.9

Comment: It's not throwing an error because we're shimming it to use 'on'.

Comment: ok...sounds ugly but if it works...  `$compile` doesn't work on selectors, pass element or html to it ... in your case needs to be element

Comment: It does something as is because when I remove the line or change it to $compile('')(scope) the binding ceases to function entirely.

It behaves identically to $compile(angular.element('#dataEntryTab'))(scope);

Comment: so this is to start angular? Not really clear what's going on. Does the ng-app work? If `ng-app` doesn't work then there is no scope for that element. WHole question is a bit confusing

Comment: Yea, so the angular app lives in a tab.  When the tab is clicked, an HTML fragment/partial view to show in the tab is fetched from the web server and then the tabLoad event is triggered, which causes that "angular hooking up code" to run.  What I have works as is, but I'm confused why I NEED that ng-model on the div above the ng-repeat.  It's like the scope that's coming through is completely empty.